# How to override HTTPForbidden in Ptah?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying out a Pyramid-based web framework, called *Ptah*, for the first time; I need to override `HTTPForbidden` view, so that people who are denied access are confronted with a login form.

```
from pyramid import security
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound, HTTPForbidden

import ptah
from ptah import form, view

@view.pview(context=HTTPForbidden)
def login_required(request):
    return str('Hello World')
```

Registering the view this way apparently does not work, but at least the default forbidden view is displayed. How do I override this view?

Answer (score 2):

It's no difference how you do HTTPForbidden in Pyramid.

Comment: You should flesh out the answer a little bit more.  As it stands now, there's not much substance here.  Perhaps point out some examples of how to do it in Pyramid?

Comment: here is pyramid documentation 

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.2-branch/narr/views.html#custom-exception-views

Comment: You should update your answer and use it to support your answer, [answers that are mostly links are not good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine using ptah 0.1 and using a scaffolding which throws a ForbiddenError, ala ptah301 scaffold.